# Office Script to Copy & Paste Range After Last Row

Tags: excel, power-automate, office-scripts

I am trying to run an office script that will copy a range consisting of the 44 rows above the last row, and paste that row one row below the last row. I see no visible errors in the script, but repeatedly does not produce the intended result and states that the "RangeByIndexes" parameter is out of range.

Here is the code I currently have. I have also specified the column count as 27. The problematic message received is tied to the fifth line.

```
`Designate workbook` function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) { 
`Designate Worksheet` const Sheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();   
`Define last row` let lastRow = Sheet.getUsedRange().getLastRow().getRowIndex();   
`log`console.log   
`copy range above last row` let sourceRange = Sheet.getRangeByIndexes(lastRow - 44, 1, 44, 28);   
`get destination range` let destRange = Sheet.getRangeByIndexes(lastRow + 1, 0, 1, 28);   ``Paste  copied range - all`` destRange.copyFrom(sourceRange,ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.all,false,false);   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Using `getRangeByIndexes` will raise an error if the `lastRow` is smaller than 44. Adding code to handle exception.
- Defining `destRange` with the top-left cell is sufficient for the `copyFrom` method.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  const selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
  let lastRow = selectedSheet.getUsedRange().getLastRow().getRowIndex();
  let startRow = lastRow - 44;
  if(startRow<0){startRow=0};
  let sourceRange = selectedSheet.getRangeByIndexes(startRow, 0, 44, 28);
  let destRange = selectedSheet.getCell(lastRow + 1, 0);
  destRange.copyFrom(sourceRange, ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.all, false, false);
}
```

**Note**: The column index is `zero-based`. Please double-check the second parameter to determine if it should be `0` or `1` accordingly.

```
let sourceRange = Sheet.getRangeByIndexes(lastRow - 44, 1, 44, 28)
```

Microsoft reference document:

> [ExcelScript.Worksheet interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.worksheet?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. Your help is greatly appreciated!